# How to make a video presentation with the possibility to go to the next or the previous "video-slide"?

Tags: video-editor, presentation

I've tried to make a Power Point presentation but I've to many videos and rendering inside so the presentation doesn't have a good portability and continuity. I would like to make directly a video, the problem is that in a video I can't go to the next or the previous slide (that in this case can be a piece of video or a conventional "static" slide with text...) like in a presentation. What software or tool can I use to have this feature in a video. Best solution would be: use the same command (right/left arrow, mouse click...) of the PP presentation to go to the next or previous video slide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently saw this page:

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/08/building-interactive-html5-videos/

Basically it uses the track element within the video element to make clickable "skip points" in the video. Javascript and html5 (with video) are pretty much amazing these days and with a little bit of experimentation I am sure you can get what you want. (Like on skip event pause the video if playing etc.)

Here is the relevant code from that page modded to your needs:

```
  <video width="480" height="204" poster="assets/sintel.jpg">
    <source src="q1fx20VZ-kNspJqnJ.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="q1fx20VZ-27m5HpIu.webm" type="video/webm">
    <track src="assets/chapters.vtt" kind="chapters" default>
  </video>

  <div id="bar"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var v = document.querySelector("video");
  var t = document.querySelector("track");
  var b = document.querySelector("#bar");

  v.addEventListener('click',play,false);
  v.addEventListener('timeupdate',update,false);
  t.addEventListener('loaded',render,false); 
  t.addEventListener('load',render,false);

  function play() {
    if(v.paused) { v.play(); } else { v.pause(); }
  }

  function update() {
    var p = v.currentTime/v.duration*100;
    b.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, #500 "+p+"%, #000 "+p+"%)";
  }

  function render() {
    var c = v.textTracks[0].cues;
    for (var i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
      var s = document.createElement("span");
      s.innerHTML = c[i].text;
      s.setAttribute('data-start',c[i].startTime);
      s.style.width = ((c[i].endTime-c[i].startTime)/888*480-7)+'px';
      s.addEventListener("click",seek);
      b.appendChild(s);
    }
  }

  function seek(e) {
    v.currentTime = this.getAttribute('data-start');
    if(!v.paused) { v.pause(); }
  }

</script>
```

The contents of the vtt file look like this:

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:01:42.000
Opening credits

2
00:01:42.000 --> 00:04:44.000
A dangerous quest

3
00:04:44.000 --> 00:05:50.000
The attack

4
00:05:50.000 --> 00:08:24.000
In pursuit

5
00:08:24.000 --> 00:10:13.000
Cave Fight

6
00:10:13.000 --> 00:12:24.000
Eye to eye

7
00:12:24.000 --> 00:14:48.000
Ending Credits
```

Answer (score 1):

Video is not directly going to handle your needs. What you need is real presentation software. Power Point is a giant joke in the industry because it is horrible. Media sequencers and real presentation software are able to deal with your situation by playing back images, video, audio and text at will.

I mostly use software designed for churches for this kind of thing so I'm most familiar with products like MediaShout and ProPresenter. There are also similar products that don't have the church specific functionality, but these packages also handle the general cases well.

Basically you give it an order of file playback and configure your transitions and the software handles playing it back when you advance the "slide".

As far as free options, you could probably use something like vlc, though I'm not sure if you could get rid of the on screen display and it won't be as easy as professional solutions.

Comment: What is "church specific functionality"?

Comment: @denjello - things like the easy ability to drop in Bible verses or lyrics for songs from libraries built in to the program.  They are features that are nice to have for media sequencing for church related events, but not helpful outside of that context.  That said, they are still relatively full featured sequencers in their own right and could be used generically.

Comment: @ AJ Henderson: Cool. Didn't know about that - is it something that can be leveraged with the drupal panopoly openchurch distro?

Comment: @denjello - no idea, don't think so.